# How to insert an array into an existing NSMutableArray at a specific index

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I've tried using

```
NSMutableArray *existingArray = [@[@"1", @"3", @"4"] mutableCopy];
NSArray *newItems = @[@"2", @"2", @"2", @"2"];
[existingArray insertObjects:newItems atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];
```

Above code ends up crashing because i'm suppose to provide all indexes for all new items.

What i want is to be able to insert newItems at position 1 of existingArray preserving the order of newItems in final array too.

Is there an easy way to provide all those indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer without comments...

```
NSInteger position = 1;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(position, newItems.count);
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[existingArray insertObjects:newItems atIndexes:indexSet];
```

Comment: this will just add new items on top of the array. You should change the first value of NSMakeRange from 0 to 1 following the example in question.

Comment: @ZeeshanTufail thanks for remark. The answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert by "replacing" an empty range:

```
[existingArray replaceObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 0) withObjectsFromArray:newItems];
```